# Resizing both PictureBoxs on window resize

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm working on an app that compares two images. For this I created window to compare results created by my app (because no program is perfect).

My problem is that no mater how much I tinker with achor property I can't get it to resize both images equaly at window resize. Both PictureBoxs have a Anchor property set on all sides and SizeMode on StretchImage in example lower. (Please don't mind buttons there are not done yet.)

What shoud I do to make both of PictureBox resize evenly?

[image: Design of window]

[image: Example of not even stretch of images]

Comment: What is the display technology you are using? WindowsForms? WPF/UWP? Since you have two image boxes, I think you need to limit them to 50% of the window width. I think a simple two column table container should be able to do that.

Comment: Window forms, and columns are set to % values

Comment: But what is the table container alligned too? And where does it get's it width from? You usually do not get around nesting containers in one another (like having the button and image area split with two horizontal rows. And the image area further split with a 2 horizontal row table or split container).

Comment: You may want to set your picture boxes to a sizing mode which retains aspect ratio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy.

Just use Split Container and make it's dock `Fill` (default) and it will resize both sides at the same time.

Also set `enabled = false` since you do not need any other feature of it but resizing with form (which will work) and you will deal with some bugs about resizing image like this.

More about it here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: actually, looks like that's what the current form already _has_.

Comment: @Nyerguds you can see on the right side of image what he has got in form.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference compared to the current table, though; that splitter can be moved by default, which gives the same problem. You never mentioned any way to get around that, so this answer has no value.

Comment: Everything good with you? Have you tried adding one to your form before talking?

Comment: I've worked with splitters multiple times, yes. They may _default_ to the center, but once they are moved the same issues will reappear. The question asked for a solution. Suggesting a different control with the same issues is not a solution.

Comment: I do not get it what you mean by move?

Comment: You can click on the splitter in the middle and drag it around.

Comment: But he doesn't need that feature so just turn it off with no border or `enabled = false`

Comment: But _you never mentioned that in your answer,_ meaning you _never actually gave a real solution._ Also, that's not even the correct way to disable moving the splitter. There's a `SplitContainer.IsSplitterFixed` property for that.